# Есть ли какие-то библиотеки для рисования маршрутов на google картах?

Tags: android, карты

Есть точки (координаты) надо нарисовать маршрут. Есть ли какие-то либы?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что [вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этого не нужны никакие либы. Это делается стандартными средствами Google.

Для начала, нужно получить маршрут. Используйте для этого [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=ru).

В ответе вы получите всю информацию по маршруту, включая навигацию. Если нужно просто нарисовать маршрут, то нас будут интересовать в ответе "routes" для получения точек маршрута и "bounds", для определения региона для маштабирования карты, чтобы маршрут показать полностью.

Пример разбора ответа и отображение маршрута на карте:

```
private GoogleMap map;

...

final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(здесь ответ от Directions API);

if(json.getString("status").equals("OK")) {

    JSONArray jsonRoutes = json.getJSONArray("routes");
    JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(0);
    final String  points = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline").getString("points");
    final JSONObject jsonBounds = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("bounds");
    final JSONObject jsonNortheast = jsonBounds.getJSONObject("northeast");
    final JSONObject jsonSouthwest = jsonBounds.getJSONObject("southwest");

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    builder.include(new LatLng(jsonNortheast.getDouble("lat"), jsonNortheast.getDouble("lng")));
    builder.include(new LatLng(jsonSouthwest.getDouble("lat"), jsonSouthwest.getDouble("lng")));
    final LatLngBounds latLngBounds = builder.build();

    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polylineOptions.color(Color.BLACK);
    polylineOptions.width(getPixelsForDp(6 /* ширина линии в dp */, getResources()));
    polylineOptions.addAll(decodePolyLine(points));

    // теперь можно рисовать маршрут на карте
    map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, getPixelsForDp(64 /* размер отступа от краев региона в dp (padding) */, getResources()));
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);


} else {
    // Гугл вернул ошибку
    new Throwable("Route Exception!");
}

...

// переводит закодированную строку PolyLine в список координат
private List<LatLng> decodePolyLine(final String poly) {
    int len = poly.length();
    int index = 0;
    List<LatLng> decoded = new ArrayList<>();
    int lat = 0;
    int lng = 0;

    while (index < len) {
        int b;
        int shift = 0;
        int result = 0;
        do {
            b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;

        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = poly.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        decoded.add(new LatLng(lat / 100000d, lng / 100000d));
    }

    return decoded;
}

...

// возвращает пиксельный размер для заданного dp
private int getPixelsForDp(int sizeInDp, Resources resources) {
    return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, sizeInDp, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

Comment: Если я дам ему список точек он вернет мне маршрут привязанный к дорогам?

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko да, или  координаты начальной и конечной точек или их адрес, почитайте документацию, я же дал ссылку. Он вернет не только маршрут, но и другие данные, включая навигацию (как проехать).

Answer (score 0):

Есть мануал в гугле, если я все верно понял, https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/

Comment: Мануал мне не нужен, стандартные АПИ уже все испробовал, не удобно. Вопрос про удобные библиотеки.

Comment: Оно ? https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Comment: Это больше похоже, думал может есть какие-то популярные о которых я не знаю?!